# Find Actor Status Akka Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Currently I have rest-endpoint-api-playframework that contains main actor to run n number of worker-actors doing batch-insertion. while in the process of doing that, I'd love to get current process of the inserts, lets say 100/1000. in order to do that, obviously I'll have the actor to report to the sender what is the status of the process.

```
class Application (implicit inj : Injector) extends Controller with Injectable {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  val mainActor = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(100).props(Props(new SupervisorActor(0))), name = "helloactor")

  val future = mainActor ? ProcessBatch  

  val workerFuture = mainActor ? CurrentProcessedItem
  result = Await.result(workerFuture, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String] 

  Ok(Json.obj("return"->result.toString))  
}
```

above, I'd expect that if `helloActor ? ProcessBatch` has completed, then I'd just return the process is completed, otherwise I'd run the `mainActor ? CurrentProcessedItem` that returns a future of the `currentProcessedItem`.

So basically I will need an indicator whether `mainActor ? ProcessBatch`   has completed or not. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

"Ask" returns you are `Future`. Therefore, `onComplete` you can do whatever you want:

```
val future = helloActor ? ProcessBatch
future.onComplete {
    case Success(result) => // Do stuff
}
```

However, I'd rather run `helloActor ? ProcessBatch` within `mainActor` and "pipe" the result to `mainActor`.

Comment: What if I hit the endpoint twice while the first process hasnt finished? That would spawn another actor wouldnt it? wouldn't I need to check if there's any ongoing actor? by the way I edited the code, helloActor is actually mainActor.